# Eigen library: Is writing to multiple columns concurrently safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, eigen

I have a matrix, say `A`, of the Eigen library and I want to fill its columns from multiple threads, i.e. the threads call `A.col(j) = xj`. Each column `j` will be written exactly once and only by one thread. So no two threads ever write to the same column but two different columns could be written at the same time.

I found a short paragraph in Eigen's docs about multi-threaded code saying `Eigen::initParallel()` should be called before using Eigen in threaded environments. However, it does not make a statement about using Eigen in a scenario as above.

Is Eigen safe to use in the way described above? Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304510/thread-safe-writing-to-eigenmatrixxd-by-row/42326595#42326595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There way you describe is safe, regardless of using Eigen or not, because no two threads ever write to the same memory location (i.e., the columns in your array.) There are no race conditions because no two threads access that same memory location if you implement it as you say you will. This will not be thread safe if there is an attempt to write to the same memory location.

One thread could even read or write to its assigned column many times without worrying about thread safety, and even another row on the same column, should you like — but just so long as nothing else is accessing that column at the same time.

I’m not sure it’s best practice or not, or if  it’s better to use smart pointers or not. Either way, the process you describe is thread safe.